# Need thoughts on a course curriculum for an entry-level programmer

Tags: java, programming-practices, sql

Would love to know your thoughts on a curriculum that will be developed for people that want to get started in the programming field. The goal of the course is to help it's students to ensure that students have an understanding of the theory and skills required to be a programmer, and have enough skills to get entry-level jobs upon graduation.

Curriculum is:

- 400 hours of instruction plus self-study.
- 40 hours of practicum

**1.    Foundation**

a.  Clarity

b.  Detail orientation

c.  Communication

d.  Compartmentalization/abstraction

e.  Typing

f.  Memory

**2.    Theory**

a.  Lexical analysis

b.  Parsing

c.  Optimization

d.  Hierarchical thinking

e.  Scope

f.  Type systems

**3.    Computer Science**

a.  Data structure (ex. sorting, searching, data structure transversal)

b.  Recursion

c.  Language structures (ex. arrays, linked lists, dictionaries, etc)

**4.    Systems Architecture**

**5.    Operating System Theory**

a.  POSIX

b.  IO

c.  Memory allocation

**6.    Object Oriented Programming**

a.  Java

b.  PL/SQL

---

Would love to know:

1. Is the above curriculum laid out clearly? If not, how would it be best to change it?
2. Are there any crucial components being missed from the above outline?
3. Should any components be removed from the above outline (considering the timeline)? Perhaps it's too detailed at certain points and is not in balance with the rest of the content?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 

Comment: You might want to consider going into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and asking people there (the whiteboard is the Programmers.SE room).  While you might not get an immediate response (depends on who is active there at the time), it is a good place for discussions.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a great start.

With a few changes. Your foundation section includes things like Memory management and abstraction. In my experience these are best handled by programmers who already have a bit of experience : a) writing programs and b) understanding the architecture of the *machines* running their programs. Furthermore, this type of instruction is best handled with lower level languages such as C or I daresay ASM. I would suggest then moving these into the actual Computer Science stage because by then certain skills will have already been obtained and you can focus more on minute and abstracted details like memory management.

The same goes for lexical analysis and presumably a bit of study on compilers and language theory. These concepts should be handled a little later on.

By the way, in terms of language usage, I think the foundations should be taught in something like python or ruby. Easy to use, dynamically typed and with a syntax and structure that generally reflects human thought. http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3882

For the heavier stuff like POSIX, Data Structures/Algorithms I think your only serious choice is C.

Object orientation can be done in java, but nowadays I think its more forward thinking to handle it in python. Or if your really bleeding edge, maybe try Go.

I think its important to include some stuff on database theory too. Like relational languages and dependence theory.

In short, there's a few things I think you are missing, but you've got a good solid start.

Comment: +1 for "python and ruby... generally reflects human thought". For me, this is the standout advantage of these two languages, light on syntax and heavy on expressibility. The odd paradox is that people grow to like a language like python BECAUSE it more closely resembles their thinking, and yet in learning to code pythonically your thoughts themselves become more pythonic... I love it!

Comment: I love that list comprehensions are basically set constructions in mathematics. And math is probably the prettiest and most concise language there is. Python just continues to reward learning and that's what makes it great software.

Comment: yes! I agree :) It seems impure that python supports so many different programming paradigms - but it is actually very cool.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. This is extremely helpful. Sounds like there's definitely still significant work to be done on the development of the curriculum. That said, we've been struggling with a bit of a paradox. Although users prefer using and learning Python (and Ruby), job opportunities are still largely dependent on knowledge of the other languages. The goal of the course is to help launch junior programmers' careers so 'employability' is of high importance to us. Thoughts?

Comment: I think this can be helpful: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/how-many-programming-languages-is-a-programmer-expected-to-be-an-expert-at its best not to think "which languages should we teach" but rather "what can we learn by teaching different languages". If you must know in terms of employability I think java, C, C++, python, knowledge of the LAMP architecture, php and SQL are musts. But once again, I must emphasize that learning is about mastering concepts. Languages are different but data structures and algorithms are language agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [ACM Curriculum Recommendations](http://www.acm.org/education/curricula-recommendations)?

ACM. the Association for Computing Machinery, is the professional society for computer software people.  They've been thinking about what needed to be taught, in what order, with what emphasis, for decades.

Comment: thank you so much for this most useful resoruce. I  haven't heard of it before. I look forward to learning more about their work and seeking their assistance re curriculum development. That said, from glancing on the website, the latest update I can see for a Computer Science curriculum is in 2008. :( That seem right?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got some great stuff in that list. Many people might not like the theory, but I really agree that it makes you a better programmer to understand the fundamental building blocks of languages.

Here's some more items I consider to be essential for entry-level programmers to have at least some exposure:

1. Testing
2. Debugging
3. Web stuff (HTTP, web applications, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the "Object Oriented Programming" before the "Computer Science" so that the concepts in the latter can be actually worked on something without assuming one is already knowledgeable in a programming language.

Testing is a big omission here.  Black box, white box and unit testing should be covered as part of what developers should know and understand within the broader scope of things.

The [SDLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life-cycle) and methodologies like Agile and Waterfall would also be things I'd suggest covering early in terms of how are projects put together and how are things done in industry.  A bit of ITIL may be useful to help illustrate how some of the bigger processes like change management and incident management are handled as this may come up within industry.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good post. One thing that I would encoruage would be if possible, have a How to implement or think on a problem. Can give them certain scenarios and explain why would you take Approach A rather than Approach B. A few examples like these, would definitely help clear thinking and clear concepts.